Display page only shows "Loading..." while the full name is in the URL in react.js?
I've been trying to work out this problem, but I'm stumped. Here's what's going on: On the page where I'm supposed to display some information, I want to show the full name of the person from a form page. But instead of showing the name, all I'm seeing is a 'loading' message, even though the full name is in the URL. It's like the page knows the name is there but just can't display it. What could be causing this, and how can I fix it? The code is below
Display
'use client';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function Display() {
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady) {
      const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(router.query);

      const first_name = searchParams.get('first_name');
      const last_name = searchParams.get('last_name');

      if (first_name && last_name) {
        setFullName(`${first_name} ${last_name}`);
        setLoading(false);
      } else {
        router.replace('/form');
      }
    }
  }, [router, router.isReady, router.query]);

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <Link href='/form' passHref>
          Go Back
        </Link>
      </nav>
      <h1>Full Name: {fullName}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

This is the form:
'use client';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import styles from '../styles/Form.module.css';

const validateName = (name) => /^[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*$/.test(name);

export default function Form() {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleSubmit = (e, displayFormat = 'normal') => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setError('');

    const trimmedFirstName = firstName.trim();
    const trimmedLastName = lastName.trim();

    if (!validateName(trimmedFirstName) || !validateName(trimmedLastName)) {
      setError('Please enter a valid first and last name (alphabetic characters and spaces only).');
      return;
    }

    const pathname = displayFormat === 'normal' ? '/display' : '/displaybonus';
    router.push(`${pathname}?first_name=${encodeURIComponent(trimmedFirstName)}&last_name=${encodeURIComponent(trimmedLastName)}`);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.formContainer}>
      {error && <p className={styles.error}>{error}</p>}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={styles.form}>
        <div className={styles.inputGroup}>
          <input
            id='firstName'
            name='firstName'
            type='text'
            value={firstName}
            onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
            placeholder='First Name'
            className={styles.inputField}
          />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.inputGroup}>
          <input id='lastName' name='lastName' type='text' value={lastName} onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)} placeholder='Last Name' className={styles.inputField} />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.buttonGroup}>
          <button type='submit' onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e, 'normal')} className={styles.submitButton}>
            Submit
          </button>
          <button type='button' onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e, 'reverse')} className={styles.submitButton}>
            Submit Bonus
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}


console.log your full name in use effect, what do you see?

This is what i get: GET /display?first_name=John&last_name=Smith 200 in 254ms

there is no .isRouter in the router from "next/navigation". the condition is never met

Add the following line before if (router.isReady):
console.log("Reached if condition", router.isReady);
Add the following inside the if condition:
console.log(first_name, last_name)
Tell me what do you see in the console?

I get "Reached if condition undefined"

the useRouter hook of next does not expose the isReady property you can simply do the check on the name of the router variable to see if it is available but looking at the documentation if the component has 'use client' it should be there.
I suggest you improve the handling of URLsearchParams retrieval using the useSearchParams hook provided by next
could be so the code:

  const router = useRouter()
  const {get} = useSearchParams()


  useEffect(() => {
    if (router) { //I think this control is superficial
      const first_name = get('first_name');
      const last_name = get('last_name');

      if (first_name && last_name) {
        setFullName(`${first_name} ${last_name}`);
        setLoading(false);
      } else {
        router.replace('/form');
      }
    }
  }, [router, get]);


If your router has well defined mast you could also use router.back() instead of the replace, if you like it even if it is more fragile and less imperative
